# "ImportError: ... Expected in: flat namespace" when setting up a mysql database

Tags: django, terminal, python-2.7, mysql-python, enthought

mySQL seems to be up and running just fine. But when I try to import MySQLdb into python I get a `ImportError: ... Expected in: flat namespace`. I think it has to do with having two different versions for python (well two different directories, same version)

OS: Mac 10.6.8

```
$ ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
7.2 Current

$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python

$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

$ easy_install MySQL-python
...
...
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
...

$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.. SUCCESS!

$ python manage.py runserver
...
...
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/_mysql.so

$ python
Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) free version -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.2-2 (32-bit)

>>> import MySQLdb
...
...
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/_mysql.so
```

So in addition to being new to django and python I'm also new to using the terminal, and I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking at.

But I can tell the obvious:

- I have two versions, 7.2 and current.
- If I call python it will call the 'Current' version. That makes sense, it's in $PATH.
- However, a version 2.7 (not 7.2) is also in PATH which I had deleted when I installed the EDP package. ...I don't fully understand what PATH is or does so I didn't want to start changing things
- MySQL-python is installed in version 7.2
- Can't run the server because a necessary file isn't in `flat namespace` and it's at the place it was installed too

Is there some way to untangle these paths (*if* that's the problem)

thank you in advance

Comment: You *did* install the MySQL client libraries, right?

Comment: er... no? I guess I haven't. Would you be able to point me at a good walk through to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Installing MySQL usually covers that, so I think you have them already now.

Comment: hmm well this question is probably pretty ignorant then, but is there a way to confirm that they are installed?

Comment: Try to import `MySQLdb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I don't think it had anything the do with the "Current" and "7.2" versions of python.

It seems to have fixed itself after doing

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql --universal
pip install MySQL-python
```

I'm not sure if the `--universal` made the diference or using pip install as opposed to easy_install

Comment: Tried this but got "-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" when trying to install the --universal version, but plain mysql no problem.